# Design of a Adder Circuit

Tags: architecture, addition

I have a adder circuit consisting of carry look ahead adders. However, I am not allowed to use the generate function to determine the sum of the two numbers. I am allowed to use basic logic operations(gates). How can I design an adder circuit under the given conditions?

Comment: This is definitely not a question for StackOverflow.  Check out some of the other StackExchange sites for a more appropriate place to post.

Comment: Maybe this will work on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have this as a part of my computer architecture problem set, so I posted it here. But anyways thanks for the link :)